# jQuery - replace HTML of 'find' elements

Tags: jquery, html

I think this is not so uncommon, so I've searched here, but can't find adequate method I need.

Basically, I want to replace strings under specific elements - `pre`.

1. sourceHTMLstrings
2. wrap with a div
3. convert(wrap) to jQueryObject
4. find `pre`
5. obtain the HTMLstrings of each `pre`
6. replace from A to B within the HTMLstrings
7. refactor the each `pre` with the new HTMLstrings
8. refactored jQueryObject Or sourceHTMLstrings

so, here's my try:

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function (org, dest)
    {
        return this.split(org).join(dest);
    };
var wrap = function (data)
    {
        return '<div>' + data + '</div>';
    };

// Data is a string which contains `pre` elements
var $data2 = $(wrap(Data))
                .find('pre') //behavior is confirmed to find several `pre`; so far so good
                .html(this.html().replaceAll(A, B));
                //Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'html'
```

or

```
.....

var $data2 = $(wrap(Data))
                .find('pre') //behavior is confirmed to find several `pre`; so far so good
                .html(this.replaceAll(A, B));
                //Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'replaceAll'
```

Basically, I could not follow how each objects are passed between methods.

I also tried to use `each` method with no success. Do you have any good idea for this?

EDIT:

the answer would be

```
var $data2 = $("<div/>");

$data2.html(Data).find("pre").html(function(_,h){
        return h.replaceAll(A, B);
});
```

then $data2 .....

```
$data2 = $("<div/>").html(Data).find("pre").html(function(_,h){
            return h.replaceAll(A, B);
```

results only `pre` collection. not the whole document range.

I think this is a good or bad example to show problem by destructive value.

Even jQuery is pretty much functional paradigm, this is so bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd work if you change your `html` function

```
.html(this.replaceAll(A, B));
```

to this :

```
.html(function(_,h){
    return h.replaceAll(A, B);
});
```

And as a sidenote, you could make it simpler :

```
var $data2 = $("<div/>").html(Data).find("pre").html(function(_,h){
        return h.replaceAll(A, B);
});
```

**Edit:**

If you want to get the entrie HTML in `Data` variable, try using `end()` after you change the HTML. This will reset the traversal and revert it to `<div/>` level.

```
var $data2 = $("<div/>").html(Data).find("pre").html(function (_, h) {
    return h.replaceAll(A, B);
}).end();
```

The above code will return the `div` we created. Its inner content will be the `pre` and other stuff in it. To get the just those stuff, add a `children()` after `end()`. This will give all the stuff in `Data` converted into DOM objects.

```
var $data2 = $("<div/>").html(Data).find("pre").html(function (_, h) {
    return h.replaceAll(A, B);
}).end().children();
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/jRjQC/

Comment: thanks hungerpain, nice technique I learn. However, the code does not work. Please review my edit.

Comment: @KenOKABE i dont get you.. could you please elaborate? do you need the entire collection of `pre` in a variable? or the entire `document`? Its EXTREMeLY unclear.

Comment: Ok, it seems work. You are very skilled on jQuery. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $data2 = $(wrap(Data)).find('pre').html().replaceAll(A, B);
```